# jQuery .AJAX is not moving on to the SUCCESS and alerting

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

See anything wrong with this?

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/nav/side',
    data: "urlpath=" + urlpath,
    success: function(data) {
        alert('Load was performed.');
      }
});
```

For some reason it's not alerting.. I'm using rails 3...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's something outside of your question that's erroring, check your console for errors.  For actual request debugging, add an `error` handler so you can see what's blowing up, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/nav/side',
    data: "urlpath=" + urlpath,
    success: function(data) {
        alert('Load was performed.');
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert('An error occured: ' + status + '\n' + error);
    }
});
```

Comment: so this is crazy, after an hour it appears that jquery is breaking in Firefox Beta 4 whenever Firebug Beta is open. If I close firebug it works fine,, jezzzzzz. Have you seen this before?

Comment: @WozPoz - Nope, but I haven't used it heavily either...they're in beta, expect the unexpected :)

Comment: More specifically, if I disable CONSOLE in firebug then everything works normally.. wowzers. First firebug monster bug i've had to deal with... filing a bug report now. Thanks Nick

Comment: @WozPoz - welcome!, hopefully they'll get it worked out soon, looking forward to daily firebug + firefox 4 usage myself.